# macのvimでの行末コマンドについての質問です。

Tags: vim, macos

mac vimをさわり初めたばかりで、書籍で勉強中です。
行末に移動するショートカットが$マークになっていますが、移動しません。Shiftキー＋$では移動できるのですが、面倒です。$マークだけでは移動できないのでしょうか。宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 何かしら良い方法を提案できるかもしれないので、行末に移動してそのあとに何がしたかったか教えてください。

Comment: すみません。行末に移動してから何かしたいというのは特になく、コマンドモードとインサートモードになれるのに、色々とショートカットを試していて、ふと疑問に思ったことでした。今まで普通のテキストエディタしか使用したことがなく少し戸惑っております。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$`のキーを<kbd>Shift</kbd>を押さないで押すと`4`です。
`4`を押しているので末尾に移動しなくて当然です。

`4`が使えなくなると、`4x`など`x`を4回繰り返せなどの命令ができなくなってしまうので、それはそれで混乱しやすい環境になってしまうと思います。

Comment: 定番だと思いますが、キーボードが106系列なら`nnoremap  ¥ $`をvimrcに書いておくと^の隣なので覚えやすいと思います。

Comment: そうですね。言われて見れば仰る通りです。納得しました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: @user25524 解決した場合は、回答にチェック（承認）をお願いします。